# Foreach a list<tuple> in an ordered fashion

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have list that is populated with data from my entityframework. This data is ordered by an ID.

I want to foreach this list in an ordered fashion so i can register which ID has already been processed. Because the ID in the list can occur more than once.

So basically its like this:

```
List<int> matchedIDs = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in tupleList)
{
   if(matchedIDs.contains(item.ID))
    {
     // do something
    }
    else
    {
     // do something else
    }
 }
```

Can this be done. So each time a new item come up in the foreach is the item with the same ID ?

PS: i am interested in matching duplicates because im inserting items in a csv file. So if the first item in tuple is the same then should not insert a new row but use the existing.

Comment: It will perform much better when you use a `HashSet<T>` for the matchedIds.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to group your results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to group by ID:

```
foreach(var group in tupleList.GroupBy(x => x.ID))
{
  var id = group.Key;
  var firstItemWithThisId = group.First();
  // iterate the items in the group
  foreach (var item in group)
  {
    // do something with the item
  }
  // do something 
}
```

Or if you are only interested in ids, use distinct:

```
foreach(var id in tupleList.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct())
{
  // do something with id
}
```

Comment: So this will actually get ID1 then ID1 again right after because its ordered ?

Comment: It creates a group for each different ID. All the items with the same ID are in the same group. The foreach iterates the groups. It executes the foreach body once for each ID.

Comment: and if my Tuple contains 4 string. like so: Type<string, string, string, sting> how would i access the last 3 items within the foreach ?

Comment: As I tried to demonstrate: group.First() gives you the first tuple in the group. You can access all its properties.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just what i needed

Comment: I can see now that this gives me the first item ONLY.. Should have noticed that. But can i get every item out and not just the first?

Comment: you can iterate the group. It is an enumerable of the items. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You dont really need to sort if you keep a list of already occurred IDs. This code should do what you need:

```
List<int> matchedIDs = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in tupleList)
{
   if(matchedIDs.Contains(item.ID))
   {
       //do something
   } else {
       matchedIDs.Add(item.ID);
       //do something else
   }
}
```

---

If you really want to sort, you can use LINQs `OrderBy` function:

```
var orderedTupleList = tupleList.OrderBy(t => t.ID);
```

---

For your purpose (essentially a lookup table) a `HashSet` would be better suited:

```
HashSet<int> matchedIDs = new HashSet<int>();
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

A `HashSet` is better because it has a lookup time of O(1), which means that it stays the same regardless how big it gets. A `List` has a lookup time of O(n), it has to run through every element to determine if the element you are looking for is in it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to select duplicates is by using `GroupBy`:

```
var grp = tupleList.GroupBy(tl => tl.Id);
var duplicates = grp.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
var nonDuplicates = grp.Where(g => g.Count() == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already keeping a list of `matchedIDs`, you do not need to sort the list. Just do it like you're already doing:

```
List<int> matchedIDs = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in tupleList)
{
  if(matchedIDs.contains(item.ID))
  {
   // do something
  }
  else
  {
   // do something else
    matchedIDs.Add(item.ID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or use a set `var matchedIDs = new HashSet<string>();` and then combine the contains check and the add, as in `if (!matchedIDs.Add(item.ID)) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have original items in list, we just need to keep processed ID list and end of process you will get how many records list not processed.

```
           List<int> matchedIDs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in tupleList)
            {
                if (matchedIDs.contains(item.ID))
                {
                    // do something
                }
                else
                {
                    if (processed) // process the records and if process then add into list.
                    {
                        matchedIDs.Add(item.ID);
                    }
                }
            }
```